# Oracle version number to integer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following query to get the version:

```
select version FROM V$INSTANCE;
```

What I want here is that the output be in integer format, so for **11.0.2.4**, it should be **11024**.
I tried `to_number` as well as `regex_substr` but am unable to figure out how I can do this using PL/SQL.

Kindly provide some guidance here.

Comment: After you've jumped through all the hoops to get your desired output, I'd ask "why"?  I strongly suspect that you are trying to solve the wrong problem, or perhaps solving a non-problem.  See 'x-y problem' at http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `REPLACE`:

```
select TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(version, '.', '')) FROM V$INSTANCE;
```

Beware of potential collisions. 
Examle: `11.1.11.2` and `11.11.1.2` give the  same output `111112`.

Comment: Can you please comment on collision?

Comment: @arsm4 Sure, added an example.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid collisions between version numbers, you need to

1. split the version number into its components;
2. convert each component to a 2-digit number (with leading 0 as required); and
3. join them together again

This query works on a table (`v`) of sample version numbers (`11.0.2.4`, `11.1.11.2`, `11.11.1.2`):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT "version", level AS l, REGEXP_SUBSTR("version", '\d+', 1, level) AS num 
  FROM v
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR("version", '\d+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT "version", LISTAGG(TRIM(TO_CHAR(num, '09'))) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY l) AS "version number"
FROM cte
GROUP BY "version"
```

Output (for the sample data)

```
version     version number
11.0.2.4    11000204
11.1.11.2   11011102
11.11.1.2   11110102
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c3122/11)